# jQuery: add an error class to input if user exits the field without filling it

Tags: jquery, blur

I have an input and I want to add an error class to it if the user exits the input without filling it.

this is my code:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="LastName" class="text" name="LastName">
```

Until now I thought of this but I don't really know how to apply it:

```
.blur(function() { if ($(this)[0].value == '') { $(this).addClass("error") } });
```

Comment: what is wrong with the code you have?  That should work

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("#LastName").blur(function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        $(this).addClass("error");
    }
});
```

You have to target your element. Since you have an ID on your text input, you can target it with `$("#LastName")`, the rest, you've already got.

Comment: You may want to use `$(this).val()` to check the value, for the sake of consistency and cross-browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have it right already more or less.

```
$('#LastName').on('blur', function () {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $(this).addClass('error');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying this

```
$('#LastName').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        //$(this).addClass("error");
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V3UPm/1/)